# Good practice to create and stock an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a better practice to stock a Javascript object in an array at creation than to push `this` ?
Thank you

```
var arrayOfObjects = [];

function MyObject() {
    
    this.foo = "foo";
    arrayOfObjects.push( this );

}

var myObject = new MyObject();

console.log( arrayOfObjects );
```

Comment: I am unsure what you think is wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: ```js arrayOfObjects.push({foo: 'foo'})```? Not sure what is needed

Comment: I've never seen it, and I've often heard that manipulating `this` can have side effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can use a spread operator so you won't mutate the state